# Lotus Notes issue with availability function with FYI calendar invites

Tags: email, calendar, lotus-notes

When I get FYI invites, how do I automatically process these to make my calendar look clear and free. For example, we may have a company outage going on for the next 3 weeks but my calendar doesn't need to be blocked off for 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the meeting in edit mode and uncheck the 'mark available' button so it doesn't use your free time? I don't remember if that works for FYI's or not.

Otherwise, you can see if the chair will set it as a 5 minute meeting at 6am that's repeating instead of booking it all day for 3 weeks so that it doesn't fill your calendar.

Or just decline it and delete the original meeting invite so it disappears altogether and then just create your own reminder on your calendar if you need to remember it.